# Hardy-Littlewood maximal function not integrable in B(0,1)

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

It is well known that if $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$, then the Hardy-Littlewood maximal function:
$$
Mf=\sup_{r>0}\frac{1}{|B(x,r)|}\int_{B(x,r)}|f(y)|dy
$$
is not in $L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Does there exist a $f$ such that $Mf$ is not integrable in $B(0,1)$?

Comment: this might inspire you https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2466203/maximal-function-is-not-bounded-on-l1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to your question is no by theorem of Stein given on the screen shot for the full proof [see here](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj7mIjauebWAhVBaFAKHRK8BhcQFggoMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.pitt.edu%2F~hajlasz%2FNotatki%2FHarmonic%2520Analysis2.pdf&usg=AOvVaw12VKyK7U_X3DY3gqT9x1Jp)

[image]

Comment: What do you mean no? The theorem says that an integrable function $f$ is not in that log space if and only if $Mf$ isn’t integrable on the unit ball

Answer (score 1):

This may help
Let $x\in B$ that is $|x|\le 1$ and let fix $r>0$  then we have $B(x,r)\subset B(0,r+1)$
indeed for $y\in B(x,r)$ we have $$|y|\le |x|+|x-y|\le r+1$$

Therefore

$$\frac{1}{|B(x,r)|}\int_{B(x,r)}|f(y)|dy \le \frac{1}{\color{blue}{|B(0,1)|r^n}}\int_{B(0,r+1)}|f(y)|dy\\=\left(\frac{r+1}{r}\right)^n\frac{1}{\color{blue}{|B(0,r+1)|}}\int_{B(0,r+1)}|f(y)|dy\le \color{red}{\left(\frac{r+1}{r}\right)^nMf(0) }$$

Comment: Of course there's no reason to think that $Mf(0)<\infty$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich yes it is true . even if it is finite taking the sup over $r$ leads to a heavy blow up

Comment: Right. So I really don't see how this helps...

Answer (score 1):

Yes. In fact such an example *must* exist, because

> > if $\lambda>0$ and $g(x)=f(\lambda x)$ then $Mg(x)=Mf(\lambda x)$.

In detail: Let $F=\chi_{B(0,1)}$, and check that $$\int MF=\infty.$$

So there exists $R_k\in(0,\infty)$ such that $$\int_{|x|<R_k}MF(x)>k^3.$$

Define $$f_k(x)=R_k^{n}F(x R_k),$$and let $$f=\sum\frac1{k^2}f_k.$$
Then $$\int_{|x|<1}Mf\ge\frac1{k^2}\int_{|x|<1}Mf_k=\frac1{k^2}\int_{|x|<R_k}MF>k.$$

Comment: see hte theorem below